# Custom grouping for all possible groups in a dataframe with missing values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, combinations

I have a dataframe which represents a set of products. I need to find all duplicate products within these products. If products have same `product_type`,`color` and `size` -> they are duplicates. This would be an easy `df.groupby('product_type','color','size')` line if I did not have a problem: some values are missing. Now I have to find all possible groups of products that might be duplicates between themselves. **This means that some elements can appear in multiple groups.**

Let me illustrate:

```
import pandas as pd


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'product_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
                       'product_type': ['shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'hat', 'hat', 'hat', 'hat', 'hat', 'hat', ],
                       'color': [None, None, None, 'red', 'blue', None, 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', ],
                       'size': [None, 's', 'xl', None, None, 's', None, 's', 'xl', None, 'xl', ],
                       })
    print df   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

for this dataframe:

[image]

I need this result - list of possibly duplicate products for each possible group (take only the biggest super groups):

[image: ![enter image description here]

So for example, lets take "shirt" with `id=1`
this product does not have color or size so he can appear in a possible "duplicates group" together with shirt #2 (which has size "s" but does not have color) and shirt #4 (which has color "red" but does not have size). So these three shirts (1,2,4) are possibly duplicates that same color "red" and size "s".

I tried to implement it by looping through all possible combinations of missing values but it feels wrong and complex.

Is there a way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

This problem of finding all combinations is likely of exponential complexity;

```
from itertools import product

def get_possible_combinations(df, columns=['size',  'product_type', 'color']):
    col_vals = []
    for col in columns:
        col_vals.append(df.loc[~df.loc[:, col].isnull(), col].unique().tolist())
    for comb in product(*col_vals):
        df_ = df.copy()
        for val, col in zip(comb, columns):
            df_.loc[:, col].fillna(val, inplace=True)
        yield df_.groupby(columns)
```

So, we can apply this function to the `df`:

```
resulting_groups = []
for g in get_possible_combinations(df):
    sorted_groups = [ind.tolist() for a, ind in g.groups.items()]
    resulting_groups.append(sorted_groups)

resulting_groups = sum(resulting_groups, [])
sorted(list(set(map(tuple, resulting_groups))), key=len, reverse=True)
```

> [(5, 6, 7),  (0, 2, 3),  (0, 1, 3),  (0, 1, 4),  (0, 2, 4),  (5, 9), 
>   (6, 7),  (6, 8),  (5, 7),  (9, 10),  (1,),  (2,),  (8,),  (3,),  (9,),
>   (4,),  (10,),  (5,),  (7,)]

This almost the same what you are looking for.

Comment: this does not provide the result I demonstrated

Comment: I significantly restructure my answer; it isn't elegant, but it works...